# android: how to keep the invisible characters in the clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard

When I add the invisible characters to the clipboard, it just disappear when I read from the clipboard?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
        LogLine logLine = adapter.getItem(i);
        sb.append(logLine.getOriginalLine());
        sb.append("\r\n");
    }
    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("simple", sb.toString());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
```

But the data read from clipboard does not contain \n characters. All text is just in one single line. How to keep those characters?

Comment: `the invisible characters`. ? You mean newline or linefeed and carriagereturn character. Please adapt your post. So you have no lines in your text afterwards.

Comment: Better ask: how to keep the lines in my text?

Comment: You are not showing how you retrieve the clipboard text. So how do you know that the lines are gone?

Comment: It's not limited to \r\n but also other characters, I just give the \r\n as an example. I checked the raw binary data and the ascii code of these "invisible character" just gone. For retrieving the data, just select any EditText and long click it, and select the paste menu.